# Swift Regex Search String Except \r\n and \t

Tags: swift, regex

I am attempting to match phone numbers that is 6 digits or more with the following regex in swift. Phone numbers can also possess paranthesis and + for country codes.

`"[0-9\\s\\-\\+\\(\\)]{6,}"`.

However, the above implementation matches `\r\n` and `\t` as well. How can I write the regex such that it will not match any `\r\n` or `\t`.

I attempted the following but didn't work:
`"[0-9\\s\\-\\+\\(\\)(^\\r\\n\\t)]{6,}"`
`"[0-9\\s\\-\\+\\(\\)(?: (\\r|\\n|\\r\\n|\\t)]{6,}"`

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `\\s` with a space, use `"(?:[ +()-]*[0-9]){6,}[ +()-]*"`. What is the code you are using the pattern in, BTW? You might also need anchors `"^(?:[ +()-]*[0-9]){6,}[ +()-]*$"` if it is not used inside `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES`.

Comment: Yet it doesn't guarantee 6 digits.

Comment: if your purpose is to match phone numbers, I suggest you to use this lib, https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. your solution worked.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using

```
let regex = "^(?:[ +()-]*[0-9]){6,}[ +()-]*$"
```

Or

```
let regex = "^(?:[ +()-]*[0-9]){6,}[ +()-]*\\z"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[ +()-]*[0-9]){6,}` - six or more repetitions of

  - `[ +()-]*` - zero or more spaces, `+`, `(`, `)` or `-` chars
  - `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[ +()-]*` - zero or more spaces, `+`, `(`, `)` or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string (`\z` is the very end of string).

If the pattern is used inside `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` you may omit the `^` and `$`/`\z` anchors.